# Google App Engine: extract just username from db.UserProperty

Tags: google-app-engine

I was wondering what is the best way to extract just the username (the portion before @ symbol) from db.UserProperty. Perhaps there is a built-in method that i don't know? the nickname method is returning full username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**email()**

```
Returns the email address of the user. If you use OpenID, you should not rely on this email address to be correct. Applications should use nickname for displayable names.
```

There is no built-in method to do that. But can you do something like this

```
from google.appengine.api import users
user =user=users.get_current_user()

email = user.email()
username = str(email).split('@')[0]
```

Comment: Bear in mind that the user part of an email address can technically contain an '@' symbol (though I've never seen one in the wild). You should use rsplit to find everything to the left of the _last_ @ symbol.

Answer (score 1):

From the Google appengine code:

> A nickname is a human-readable string which uniquely identifies a Google
>     user, akin to a username. It will be an email address for some users, but
>     not all.

So it maybe the username or the email depending on the account.